# When I use regular run time (mins) my error is 25 but when I take a log of the runtime (to make it normal) my error is 0.3?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, metrics

Im doing a typical Machine Learning regressor problem. There are 800 data points and 6 features. The best model Extra Trees Regressor returns 30 for Root Mean Square Error. I take a log transformation to make the extreme data less influential. The log transforms the data from skewed right to be normally distributed as well. The error is only 0.54 so why such a drastic change

log(30) = 1.4
I do understand my statistics knowledge is not the best but this seems quite strange for me. I haven't done any tuning to the parameters.

With that being said, what error should I believe? What is the interpretation of each?

Take a log of predicted values

```
pricing['runtime.min'] = np.log(pricing['runtime.min'])
```

Function to evaluate a model

```
def evaluate(model, test_features, test_labels):
    predictions = model.predict(test_features)
    #Absolute Error
    errors = metrics.mean_absolute_error(test_labels, predictions)
    #Mean Square Error
    MSerrors = metrics.mean_squared_error(test_labels, predictions)
    #Root Mean Squared Error
    RMSE = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(test_labels, predictions))
    print('Model Perfomance')
    print('Average MAE Error: {:0.4f} degrees. '.format(errors))
    print('Average MSE Error: {:0.4f} degrees. '.format(MSerrors))
    print('Average RMS Error: {:0.4f} degrees. '.format(RMSE))
    return 'end of test'
```

Extra trees regressor

```
et_params = {'n_estimators': 1000,  'max_features':2}
et = SklearnExtra(clf = ExtraTreesRegressor(), seed = Seed, params = et_params)
et.fit(x_train, y_train)

base_models = [rf, et, gb, ada, xg]

for i in base_models:
    print('Model ' + i.name())
    print('Training: '+str(evaluate(i, x_train, y_train)))
    print('')
    print('Model ' + i.name())
    print('Test: '+ str(evaluate(i, x_test, y_test)))
    print('Test MAPE '+ str(mean_absolute_percentage_error(i, y_test, x_test)))
```

```
Model ExtraTreesRegressor(bootstrap=False, criterion='mse', max_depth=None,
                    max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
                    min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                    min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                    min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=None,
                    oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
                    warm_start=False)
Model Perfomance
Average MAE Error: 0.0165 degrees. 
Average MSE Error: 0.0079 degrees. 
Average RMS Error: 0.0887 degrees. 
Training: end of test

Model Perfomance
Average MAE Error: 0.3572 degrees. 
Average MSE Error: 0.2957 degrees. 
Average RMS Error: 0.5438 degrees. 
Test: end of test
```

Comment: What is the difference in the statistics of your predicted values between the models? Min, Max, Mean, Std? Did you only transform the one feature, or your targets as well?

Comment: You might also ask on the [datascience.se] stack exchange, as this question is more about the theory than the coding

Comment: I only transform the target not the feature and that makes me question if I should transform the features as well!

Comment: @G.Anderson I tried Data Science Exchange before but it is quite hard to get a reply on there.

Comment: @G.Anderson do you think I should transform my features as well?

Comment: You could also try [stats.se], I think they're more responsive, if my answer doesn't prove useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't tell you whether you *should* do something, you have to decide if it makes sense for the data.

But that's why I asked in the comments about the transform and the statistics, if you changed the scale of your targets, you can't use the absolute difference between the two models for analysis. If your initial model had a RMSE of 30, but the range of predicted values is 0 to 100 and the standard deviation is 20 (for example) then that's not great. But in your new model if the data is 0 to 10 and the st.dev. is 3.5, then a rmse of .5 might be better.

The correct answer is a little bit subjective, but boils down to this:
If you make predictions on real world data using the model in question, is the error metric within acceptable tolerances for the task at hand? For your initial model, is your business case such that 30 (seconds? Minutes?) or difference in run time between predicted or actual will be "close enough"? Is .54 log-milliseconds enough to render your predictions useless for the second model?

See the "Useful" part of ["All models are wrong, some are useful"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57407/what-is-the-meaning-of-all-models-are-wrong-but-some-are-useful)